# How to change tab control background of header in silverlight 3?

Tags: silverlight-3.0, tabcontrol

I'm trying to figure out how to change the color of tab headers in TabControl. The whole tab control has another color than white and it's why it looks so ugly.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can set the tab header color right into the TabItem tag:

```
<basics:TabItem BorderBrush="#00426b" FontSize="12" Background="#00426b">
```